# D3 transition and update in chord diagram

Tags: d3.js, transition, chord-diagram

I'm using a d3 chord diagram to visualize some data from multiple JSON files. There is one JSON file per year, and when I choose a year (a select input or a button), the data should be updated.

My approach is like this:

```
// ...
// Setup width, height, radius, chord layout and append the svg container element
// ...

// Load the default data file
d3.json("data/m2010.json", function(matrix) {
    render(matrix);
});

// ...
// Usual render function, like the examples of mbostock.org
// ...

// Listener: the user want to change the year
d3.select('#year').on('click', function(){
  d3.event.preventDefault(); // Actually it's an href
  d3.selectAll('.groups').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.chords').remove();      
  d3.json("data/m2011.json", function(matrix) {
     render(matrix);
  });
});
```

So what I do is remove all the groups and chords of the previous visualization and then load the new data. I don't think that this is the d3-way to do that.

What I want to do is add some kind of transition between visualizations.
I've read about the update pattern (enter, update, exit), but don't know how I could adapt it to my problem.

The `render` function and all the source is [here](http://jsbin.com/ubazow/1/edit) (it's just the JavaScript)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff how did you find it? :) Thank you so much.

Comment: It's linked on the D3 examples page.

Comment: Related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813723/change-and-transition-dataset-in-chord-diagram-with-d3/21923560#21923560