# Adding and removing elements from D3 Visualization with animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, chord-diagram

long time user first time asking a question here (first time I haven't been able to solve a problem using answers I searched for). I've recreated the uber chord chart in JS D3 with my own data. My implementation can be found [here](https://www.purdue.edu/oir/test/IanJS/), though that address may not stay good forever so here is the code (forgive a few misalignments throughout):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.layout.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="footer">
        Purdue OIR Testing - Migration
        <div class="hint">mouseover groups to highlight</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tooltip"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


//import the data and call the draw chords function 
d3.text("migrationdata.csv", function(data) {
    var matrix = d3.csv.parseRows(data).map(function(row) {
        return row.map(function(value) {
            return +value;
        });
    });
    d3.text("headersColors.csv", function(headerdata) {
    var headersColors = d3.csv.parseRows(headerdata);
    var headers = headersColors[1];
    var colors = headersColors[2];

    drawChords(matrix, headers, colors);
 });
});

//create the chord viz
function drawChords (matrix, headers, colors){

    var w = 980,
        h = 800,
        r1 = h / 2,
        r0 = r1 - 110,
        fadeOutA = 0,
        fadeInA = 0.8;

    var fill = d3.scale.category20c();

    var chord = d3.layout.chord()
        .padding(.02)
        .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
        .sortChords(d3.descending);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r0)
        .outerRadius(r0 + 20);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
        .attr("id", "circle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("r", r0 + 20);
        //.attr("fill-opacity",0);

    //assign the matrix
      chord.matrix(matrix);

    //create the groups
      var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
          .data(chord.groups)
        .enter().append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "group")
          .on("mouseover", mouseover)
          .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

      g.append("svg:path")
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return colors[d.index]; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.index]; })
          .attr("d", arc);

      g.append("svg:text")
          .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
                + "translate(" + (r0 + 26) + ")"
                + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
          })
          .text(function(d) { return headers[d.index]; });

      var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
          .data(chord.chords)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr("class", "chord")
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(colors[d.source.index]).darker(); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.source.index]; })
          .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(r0))
          .on("mouseover", function (d) {
              d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("visibility","visible")
                .html(chordTip(d))
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 100) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 100) + "px");  
               })
           .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

      function chordTip (d) {
        var p = d3.format(".1%"), q = d3.format(",.2r")
        return "Migration Info:<br/>"
          +  headers[d.source.index] + " → " + headers[d.target.index]
          + ": " + Math.round(d.source.value) + "<br/>"
          + headers[d.target.index] + " → " + headers[d.source.index]
          + ": " + Math.round(d.target.value) + "<br/>";
      }

      function groupTip (d) {
        return "College Info:<br/>"
            + headers[d.index] + " : " + Math.round(d.value) + "<br/>";
        }

      function mouseover(d, i) {
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("visibility", "visible")
          .html(groupTip(d))
          .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 80)+"px"})
          .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 130)+"px";})

        chordPaths.classed("fade", function(p) {
          return p.source.index != i
              && p.target.index != i;
        });
  }

}



// Returns an event handler for fading a given chord group.
function fade(opacity) {
  return function(d, i) {
    svg.selectAll("path.chord")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
      .transition()
        .style("stroke-opacity", opacity)
        .style("fill-opacity", opacity);
  };
}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine, and is totally functional. It shows student movement between colleges from Fall 2012-Fall 2013 (I plan to make the explanation on screen a bit better as I go). My next step is to make this drillable. So for instance, if you click a college I want to expand that college out into its departments and show the chords between various departments and "Other" which would be the combination of all other colleges. Further, you would be able to drill into department to get major-level detail in the same fashion. I have all the raw data I need to do this, and I am fairly confident I know how I can use it to create the new matrices on the fly when clicking on a group.

My question is, doing what I describe above is all fairly straight forward if I just dump the current viz for a new one with new data each time, but that's going to be a harsh transition. I'd prefer something with animation like [this](http://exposedata.com/tutorial/chord/latest.html). However, that example only works if your matrices are the same size on each end of the transition. Because of how I'd like to drill into this data, that will not always be true for me. I could have fewer or more groups/chords than I did before. My question is, if I create a new chord layout with a bigger/smaller matrix than what is currently on screen, can I somehow smoothly animate the new/un-needed groups/chords in/away? If so, how would I go about this and are there any examples out there?

I'm still fairly new to D3 but I'm trying to learn quickly as there is a ton of demand here for these types of visualizations. If there is a tutorial on this feel free to simply link it, I've been researching this on and off for a few days now and haven't found anything satisfactory explaining how to smoothly add/remove elements in a d3 layout.

Comment: So long as you have all the matrices with the appropriate label arrays organized, you should be able to figure out a smooth transition even with different sized matrices.  I wrote up a [long discussion of chord diagrams and transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21923560/3128209) not too long ago, which should help get you started, although that example transitions to different numbers but the same categories.  You'll have to decide what you want the transition to look like.  Will the clicked-on group just divide into smaller pieces, or will it also expand to take over the entire circle?

Comment: Thanks Amelia. That is a great deal of awesome information and I think that may be all I need. I'm thinking for now that the group will 'split' and that all those new groups retain the same color to indicate they belong to the same college/department. If that gets too busy, I'll think about how to handle it when I get there. For now, it looks like your explanation of enter and exit will do the thick but I'll read up, try some things, and come back if I have further questions. Thanks!

Comment: All right! I've made a ton of progress on this. Here's what I have so far:
https://www.purdue.edu/oir/test/CODOchord/
The animation is a little chaotic since I'm not really working with your code as intended, but that's something I can improve upon later. One big question on something that I just couldn't get to work. When I use the uber example, I get tooltips that immediately pop up on mouseover, and I can't get tooltips for faded out chords. In this version, I can get tooltips on faded out chords and I have to rely on the hover title rather than a tooltip div. How can I get my old tooltips?

Comment: As far as transitions, I think what you want is to have your entering/exiting elements just fade in in place instead of transitioning in shape.  That actually should simplify your code.  For your tooltips, you probably want to separate your mouseover and mouseout event handlers as named function so that you can easily add or remove them on update (you remove an event handler by replacing it with `null`, like `.on("mouseover", null)`).  Another option is to leave the mouseover functions, but set the `pointer-events` style to `none` on "faded out" elements, so they don't trigger mouse events.

Comment: Now it works great! I'll need to discuss some functionality/formatting with my coworkers before I move on to cleaning up the page a bit, but this works exactly as I'd like it to now. Thanks for your help! Not sure what to mark as an "answer", though.

Comment: For an answer, could you write up your own summary of how you handled the problem?  (You can link to my extra long answer, and then just describe how you adapted that).

Comment: I'm still working on this, I want to make something more final (and linkable) for my answer. I'm now running into an issue where the exit transitions on the chords don't work. Any chords that can't be re-purposed simply pop out when the animation completes, and it is a bit jarring. Now that I look back at your original fiddle, it seems like it is happening there as well. I'm also noticing that exiting arcs don't fade out either, they simply pop out. Seems like the exit functions aren't working quite as intended. Any idea how to fix? I'll keep looking in the meantime.

Comment: Okay, I think this isn't working because anything that needs to exit is not in the new dataset and therefore isn't selected when we do a selectAll on the new layout. I'll need to find a way to select the chords from the last layout that aren't in the new layout and transition/remove them. I think.

Comment: You're right, the fade away affect isn't quite working...  The problem is that there is a CSS transition on opacity (to handle the mouse-out fade effect) and that seems to be cancelling out the d3 transition: d3 keeps on setting opacity values, but the CSS then takes half a second to implement them!  You can (a) skip the d3 transition and just let the CSS handle it (remembering to still put the "remove" statement after a transition); or, (b) to control timing, use `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity` to avoid conflicts with the CSS.

Comment: Okay, if I use fill-opacity and stroke-opacity to fix this, the pop-out happens immediately instead of post-animation. This still looks MUCH better, but still isn't smooth. I actually changed my mouseover to induce a faded effect instead of a total fadeout (I think it looks better here), so if I let CSS handle it there will definitely be a pop from low-opacity to zero opacity at some point. I wonder why the transition doesn't appear to be happening? There isn't anything in CSS messing with fill-opacity and stroke-opacity.

Comment: Can you post your latest code (or at least the relevant snippet)?  It was working when I played around with fill-opacity/stroke-opacity on the fiddle earlier...

Comment: https://dev.www.purdue.edu/oir/test/CODOchord/ <- this is where I'm working currently, if you need all the code. The relevant snippet is:
chordPaths.exit().transition()
 .duration(1500)
 .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
 .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
 .remove();

Comment: Oh, of course -- when transitioning attributes, you have to set the attributes' starting values first, or it will just jump to the final value.  I was using `style` which doesn't have the same problem, since it uses `getComputedValue` to set the starting value.  See http://fiddle.jshell.net/4wYPa/ -- the value set using an attribute changes immediately after the delay, the value set using style actually transitions.

Comment: Oh that is fantastic and makes perfect sense. Alright, I need to clean my code up a bit and get this loaded into the Purdue web template to be put somewhere more permanent that I can link to, then I'll write up a detailed answer. Thanks for all your help Amelia, I have one more question but I think it deserves its own separate question. I'm trying to re-order the chords to avoid overlap where possible, but can only find methods to sort ascending/descending by chord value.

Comment: That is going to be tricky, and definitely worth a new question.  You might want to look at matrix cluster-sorting algorithms like the one used in [the co-occurrence matrix example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/).

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer this, I used AmeliaBR's excellent answer to this other question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813723/change-and-transition-dataset-in-chord-diagram-with-d3/21923560#21923560)

I made a few changes to this solution:

First, I updated the group exit to have a starting opacity. The way it was coded, anything that exited would pop out rather than fade out if I used attributes rather than styles, since transition requires a starting attribute value and can't grab the current value:

```
        groupG.exit()
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 1)
        .transition()
            .duration(300)
            //change fill and stroke opacity to avoid CSS conflicts
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
            .remove(); //remove after transitions are complete
```

This does have the effect of causing faded chords to quickly fade up and down during the animation, but it looks smoother than pop-out so I kept it.

Also, I had issues in IE, specifically because our installation of IE on campus defaulted document mode to IE7, and you need at least IE9 for this to work. It just took one line of code to force this change:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Also, pointer-events doesn't work in IE earlier than IE11 and I used a div tooltip instead of the tooltips in the example, so I needed to set the tooltip far enough away from the mouse that the user wouldn't touch it. This is a... less than elegant solution, and I would like to find a better one but it probably isn't worth the time.

My final solution can be found [here](https://www.purdue.edu/datadigest/?dashboard=StudentMigrationChord). I plan on updating this with 1) unscrambling some of the un-necessary chord overlap and 2) making my data updating functions work with a template dataset, instead of the one specific dataset I created for this purpose.