# d3 chord diagram on angular2

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I would like to implement a chord diagram with Angular2. Researching, I found that [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) library implements that kind of diagrams, but if anybody knows other libraries to implement it those are welcome :)

I already have d3 integrated with Angular2 in two ways: one through [d3-ng2-service](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service), and another installing the typings of d3.

There are some examples here in SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813723/change-and-transition-dataset-in-chord-diagram-with-d3/21923560#21923560) awesome answer, but when I try  to integrate into my app some methods doesn't exists and I don't know how can achieve this. For example `d3.svg.arc` is not recognized.
There are other useful links with examples of chord diagrams, like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewRP/7468330) or [this](https://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/chord.html)

Anybody has experience with chord diagrams on Angular2 and can drive me on the good way?

Any resource is welcome, like libraries (free or paid), tutorials...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That example uses D3 v3.x, you're probably using D3 v4.x.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, and it can helps, finally I resolved using [echarts](http://echarts.baidu.com/download.html)

There is a chord diagram implementation [here](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=graph-circular-layout) and an angular2 integration [here](https://github.com/xieziyu/angular2-echarts).

Comment: That does not really resolve but rather circumvents the issue, right?

Comment: Yep, i asked for d3 library because it was the only library that I saw that had chord diagrams, but researching I found echarts and it fits to me.